# How do I run a local ASP.NET MVC application with Entity Framework from another computer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-express

I am currently learning ASP.NET MVC with Individual Accounts authorization and Entity Framework. My database (`.mdf`) is in the `App_Data` folder (SQL Server Express) and my connection string is pointing to this file.

When pushing to Git I have this database file approved in my `.gitignore` even though it's a database file.

My solution has two projects (layers). This is the general structure (I am not allowed to embed images because of my current low reputation since I am a new user):

[image: Structure]

This is a simple test application that I will not deploy. However, when opening my solution from another computer I both need to restore nuget packages and then enable migrations.

I want this solution to be fully runnable from another computer that has Visual Studio installed. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Since you're using SQL Server Express, having only Visual Studio installed on another PC is not sufficient - you must also ensure that SQL Server Express is installed. This has to be installed before you can run your app.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below and run your program:

1- Put your database in a database engine and set its IP in WebCunfig.This is automatically OK when making the Model.

2- Disable your previous connections and rebuild your anti-framework according to the new database address

3- If you are using a standalone database, your MDF file has nothing to do with your project and it is better to put it somewhere else.

4- Put your project in the GIT repository.

5- Get a clone of this repository on another computer.

6- Run your sulution on other computer.

I have a project with 6 different layers and I integrate these into 4 separate computers. We have a central git and all 4 computers use that repository. However, if you change the database, you will have to update your model, and you may have a conflict with your friends in this case.